# Richtextbox and Docx converting

Tags: c#, richtextbox, docx, openxml-sdk, novacode-docx

I'm making an editor for Word documents in C#. And I'm using a RichTextBox to create text with its formatting, and add a slice of XDocumento docx.

Someone could tell me if you have any way of converting?? include formating...

This example would already be more complex:

**RichTextBox format:**

```
{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1046{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs17 A \\b Nissan \\b0 est\\'e1 \\i mesmo \\i0 disposta a \\ul fincar \\ulnone seus p\\'e9s em solo \\cf1 brasileiro\\cf0 . \\par\r\n}\r\n
```

**to this, OpenXml Document format: (default for docx)**

```
<w:p w:rsidR = "00685F88" w:rsidRDefault = "00685F88">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:widowControl w:val = "0"/>
                <w:autoSpaceDE w:val = "0"/>
                <w:autoSpaceDN w:val = "0"/>
                <w:adjustRightInd w:val = "0"/>
                <w:spacing
                    w:after = "0pt"
                    w:line = "12pt"
                    w:lineRule = "auto"/>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">A</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:bCs/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">Nissan</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">está</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:i/>
                    <w:iCs/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">mesmo</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">disposta a</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:u w:val = "single"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">fincar</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">seus pés em solo</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>`enter code here`
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:color w:val = "FF0000"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>brasileiro</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts
                        w:ascii = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:hAnsi = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
                        w:cs = "Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
                    <w:sz w:val = "17"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val = "17"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space = "preserve">.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
```

and the opposite too.

Did not want to do it manually.

In Micrsoft Office Word, you can convert the RTF format (used in richtextbox) to DOCX. But I can not find the solution to this in Wird library.

Thanks.

Comment: By using RTF, you are making life rather difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex. This pattern will match the first example, `{Text.*?"(.*?)"}`, and here's a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/dT6bZ3) to prove it. Then the `C#` for this would be:

```
var val = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "<w:p><w:r><w:t>$0</w:t></w:r></w:p>");
```

Comment: Thx Michael,
I got to thinking about it, the problem would be the various types of formats that I would have to convert. In this case only has text.
I add another example.

Comment: @ThiagoTozzi, unfortunately there's no way around it. You'll need to build multiple Regex patterns for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the .Text option when referencing the RTFTextBox. For example, mytextbox.rtf vs mytextbox.text. At least thats the way it works in Visual Studio 2010.